# How to remove username from folder security tab in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Hello everyone I'm trying to remove username from the folder security tab but I can remove the user's access rule from folder and the username is still exists. Here is my code as you can see at below

```
public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string FileName, string UserName){
            string DomainName = System.Environment.UserDomainName;

            DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);
            DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

            myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(DomainName + "\\" + UserName,FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow));
            myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

        }
```

So how can remove the username from folder security tab ?